# How to consume streaming video from a password server?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, streaming, credentials

We have a Linux server where we keep several product videos. I am writing a ASP page (vb.net) for our internal site (for employees only) that supposed to play those videos on demand using a Javascript media player (I didn't choose one yet but I am leaned to use player.js). Initially I was thinking on using a Telerik control called radMediaPlayer, but now I imagine that JS may be a better option.

At first glance it is an easy task but the problem is that our server demands credentials and I have NO IDEA how to consume streaming video in such situation. I tried Google but got no luck.

Any direction appreciated!

PS: I forgot to mention that the server is an *internal* server reachable through a direct path like \\myserver\videos\ and not a http server.

Comment: Could be very wrong with this, but I think you might be going down the wrong path.  I'm assuming your asp page is hosted in IIS, I think the easier way would be to create a virtual directory which has the authentication in IIS for the web app.  The VD will point to the folder with your videos then from you page, will in effect look like local resources

Comment: @Hursey you are correct, my ASP page will be in IIS. Your idea is great, I just have to figure how to do this. Thanks!